# Проблема с вызовом __setitem__

Tags: python

Пытаюсь унаследовать класс [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)`.Browser`:

```
from mechanize import Browser
class LLManager(Browser, object):
    IS_AUTHORIZED = False
    def __init__(self, login = "", passw = "", *args, **kwargs):
        super(LLManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_handle_robots(False)
```

Но когда я делаю что-нибудь такое:

```
lm["Widget[LinksList]_link_1_title"] = anc
```

выдаётся ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    lm["Widget[LinksList]_link_1_title"] = anc
TypeError: 'LLManager' object does not support item assignment
```

А когда вот так:

```
>>> m.__setitem__("Widget[LinksList]_link_1_title", anc)
>>> print lm.form
  <TextControl(Widget[LinksList]_link_1_title=Р”Р¶РёРЅСЃРѕРІС‹Р№ С‡РµР»)>
  <TextControl(Widget[LinksList]_link_1_url=http://)>
```

, то всё работает.

Метод `__setitem__` класса у `Browser` и выше не перегружен.

Почему мой класс или экземпляр не наследуют этот метод как у родителя?

Comment: Судя по object, речь идёт о Python-2?

Comment: Python 2.7, ага.
Пардон, я немного перепутал. В данном случае, речь идёт о `__getitem__` и `__setitem__`, которых во всей цепочки наследования до верхнего класса нет.

Comment: Ну подправьте соответствующим образом сам вопрос.

Comment: Довольно удивительно… Кажется, должно работать… Сейчас скачаю этот mechanize и попробую понять, что могло пойти не так…

Comment: Раньше всё время не наследовал классы от Browser, а добавлял атрибут к классу, что-то типа:
    self.br = Browser()

Решил сейчас не париться и сделать наследника, но тут-то запары и начались :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так всё кристально ясно. Действительно, во всём дереве наследования нет аттрибута `__setitem__`. Зато у `Browser` определён метод `__getattr__`, который проверяет, подключена ли к нему форма и, если подключена, то возвращает её аттрибут (т.е. вызовется `__setitem__` этой формы).

Вы же наследуете свой класс от `object`, тем самым он превращается в [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle), а там уже всё немного не так работает :).

---

Основная идея такая: лучше не смешивать старые классы с новыми, а то можно напороться на что-нибудь ;).

Comment: Я пошёл читать ман. А можете подсказать, что делать? Дело в том, что если я не буду наследоваться от object, то возникает другая ошибка (http://jezuz-chrizt.livejournal.com/402864.html)

Comment: Это правда, super работает только с new-style классами :).

Comment: Вы решите, хотите Вы new-style class или нет. Если не хотите, то вместо super указывайте явно имя родительского класса, когда хотите родительский метод вызвать.

Comment: так как мне быть? допустим, я скопирую метод __getattr__ из Browser или буду вызывать его через super. но есть подозрение, что это не один подводный камень. И тут либо убирать из родителей object и получать ошибку, либо что-то делать с тем, что уже накодил. Как поступить?

Comment: Да плюньте вы на это говно. Сделайте просто нормальный метод setTitle с нужными параметрами, а не этот нечитабельный строковой бред в качестве ключа.

Comment: Как быть? Прочитайте мой предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: У экземпляра Browser все параметры форм так задаются.

Comment: Пойду попробую сделать по-старинке. Но есть у меня предчувствие, что это далеко не единственная проблема.

Comment: Кстати, да. Я уже так пробовал. Получается вот что:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "LJLLManager.py", line 53, in <module>
        lm = LLManager(login, passw)
      File "LJLLManager.py", line 15, in __init__
        Browser.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Browser instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: Ну так и передайте ему self первым аргументом, как просит :)

Comment: Во, я невнимательный. Пардон ещё раз =)
Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Дык, не работает, я ж всё показал. Заходим куда-нибдь, где есть форма, выбираем форму (метод select_form()) и через строковые ключи просматриваем и редактируем поля формы.

Comment: Что? Где не работает? Если Вы не забыли убрать object из списка родителей Вашего класса, то должно работать!

Comment: Да не, Вы написали, что с super всё должно работать, я и ответил на него =) А без super, конечно, убрал object, сделал вызов __init__ напрямую через родительский класс и всё окей. А вот с super ничё не работает, собственно о чём я всё и толкую выше.

Comment: Чёрт, а вот если пытаться вникнуть в саму проблему с вызовом __setitem__ в new-style классах, но ничего не понятно :(. Я уже мозг сломал :(.

Comment: Ну тут у Вас явно больше опыта. Я уже смирился с тем, что нужно по-старинке всё писать :(

Comment: Йее нашлось! Для new-style классов __getattribute__ не вызывается, когда речь идёт о встроенных в синтаксис языка фичах. http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?#new-style-special-lookup

Comment: Это значит тупик?

Comment: Это значит, что у Вас уже всё давно должно работать о_0. В чём проблема-то сейчас?